# How to load texture from MySql database with three.js?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, three.js

How can I load the model's texture from a MySql database based on the user that is logged in using three.js and php? What I want to do is have the user login and only show the texture on the model associated with that user. Can I just "echo" that column from the users database information within the js or would I have to do it a different way? I've attempted to find the answer through Google as well as using the three.js github site but with no success. I'm somewhat new to this idea so a push in the right direction would be much appreciated or even a simple example.

Comment: What exactly do mean with texture? Only the diffuse map (= image file ) of an material or the complete material including diffuse color, specular color and so on?

Comment: Sorry, I neglected to mention that. My model is baked to use only one texture file. All colors etc are baked into one image

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In three.js a model is typically defined in a json file.

Under materials there is an entry for the diffuse map, something like this:

```
{
    ...
    "materials": [{
        ...
        "mapDiffuse": "texture.png"
    }]
}
```

So you need to point the mapDiffuse to your php script, something like this:

```
{
    ...
    "materials": [{
        ...
        "mapDiffuse": "getTexture.php?id=1"
    }]
}
```

In your php script you can dynamically load the image and return it to the browser.
It is not so complex. I done this in node.js before and it was just a view lines of code.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but could you ellaborate a little more on the PHP side? Also, where exactly did you locate that materials section? Is that within the JS file of three.js or within the json file of a model? Thank you again.